# Indian railway e ticket queries

Tags: trains, tickets, india

I would like to known that i booked 4 e railway ticket i have a doubt that out of 4 if only 2 tickets get confirmed and 2 remains wait list can i board the train

train name : Swaraj  express
date: 18 april 2014
class: sleeper
journey : mumbai to delhi
waiting status: pqwl {pooled quota wait list}

Answer (score 3):

If an e-ticket consists of partially confirmed and partially wait list, all the names present on the E-Ticket are added on the reservation chart and you can travel since the Ticket will be considered valid during the journey. For confirmation, you can visit the following section of IRCTC website:

https://www.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Waitlisted_E-Ticket.html

Mostly there are chance that the Waitlist will be converted to an RAC or confirmed seat during the journey depending on the turnout. The TTE has to give preference in such cases while alloting the seat.

Answer (score 1):

Any waitlisted seat on e-ticket are cancelled as soon as the chart is prepated. And the 100% ticket amount for the waitlisted seat is refund to the account that was charged.
If you travel with such an e-ticket, you will be considered travelling without ticket and you will be fined.

You still have a long time for the ticket to confirm however my experience with PQWL is that they don't confirm.

You can take a general ticket, board the train. Then talk to the TC and upgrade your ticket. However it is unlikely that he will be able to provide you a seat. You will have to adjust with the other.

Comment: Just letting future visitors know that this is not factual, if you have partially confirmed tickets

Answer (score 1):

As per revised rules, the waitlisted e-tickets will be cancelled automatically.
See the section 3.4 (3rd point) of [this](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/refund_Rules.html) page.

However [high court already ordered](http://www.medianama.com/2014/07/223-indian-railways-irctc-ticket-waitlist/) to make it same as physical ticket (i.e. it should not cancelled as ticket purchased from reservation counter).